# Why isn't my lock channel command working??? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I created a lock channel command but when I test it, it gives me no error and doesn't lock the channel. I searched the internet but couldn't find any working lock commands. Here's my code.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lock(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel=None):
    channel = channel or ctx.channel
    overwrite = channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
    overwrite.send_messages = False
    await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
    await ctx.send('Channel locked.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using set_permissions wrongly, pass in the permissions name and its value.

Overwrites should be used if you want more than 1 target, here it is only 1 so we can directly use the permission name.

Below is the revised code:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lock(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel=None):
    channel = channel or ctx.channel
    await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
    await ctx.send('Channel locked.')
```